# Is this a security flaw in Firefox 18.0?

Tags: web-browser, firefox

I had a couple of .mht files which opened in IE, a browser I never use. I renamed their extension to .HTML to run it in Firefox. When I opened the file in Firefox, Firefox created new tabs endlessly. I had to close it to stop it.

Is this a security flaw in Firefox?

Comment: Even if not a security flaw, it's a bug and submit it to FF's bugzilla

Comment: It sounds like more of an annoyance rather than a security flaw.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firefox does not support MHT files without [addons](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/unmht/).

It is possible that you have tricked Firefox into opening each MIME object from the MHT file into a new tab. It is doubtful that this could turn into a security flaw.

---

**Update:**

I confirm that behavior with a valid MHT file. **It is a Firefox configuration issue**. By default, Firefox will not recognize the MHT and will ask you for a "Open with" program. If you select to open with Firefox and check "Do this automatically for files like this from now on", then it goes into a loop and will open many new tabs. It will stop if you press the Escape key.

This [Mozilla support article](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/firefox-repeatedly-opens-empty-tabs-or-windows) is about the same symptom and contains a configuration fix.